# How to configure GKE to save control plane logs only?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

My GKE cluster has many pods that I don't control. Some of these pods produce an excessive amount of logs. These logs are all sent to Stackdriver Logging which becomes very expensive for me to ingest. I've turned off log ingestion to save money, but now I can not find any control plane logs such as the cluster autoscaler logs.

Is there a way to configure GKE to send only control plane logs to Stackdriver Logging?

Comment: Have a look at this, [Audit Logging](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/audit-logging) should be helpful.

Comment: I recommend using Log Exclusions, instead of only ingesting specific logs, you can exclude whichever logs you don't want